# Symfony2 routing: How to request that the route will be taken from only one template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, routes

I heve an embedded controller in my base template. It's a search bar.
For the search bar controller, I have a route "myProject/search".

What I would like is that this route will be taken only when the template where I am embedding the controller (base.html.twig) will call it, and not when i manually put in the browser: "myproject/search".

Any idea on how to do that.

Comment: Why -1 ? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, since some time you can't do it:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

quote from the docs:

> Even though this controller will only be used internally, you'll need
>   to create a route that points to the controller
>
> (...)
>
> Since Symfony 2.0.20/2.1.5, the Twig render tag now takes an absolute
>   url instead of a controller logical path. This fixes an important
>   security issue (CVE-2012-6431) reported on the official blog. If your
>   application uses an older version of Symfony or still uses the
>   previous render tag syntax, you should upgrade as soon as possible.

Anyway, I guess, you can try do it yourself by passing some "secret" argument to search action when you call it from your template. Next in the action you check if the argument was passed to it, and if not you throw 404.

Another way to achieve your goal is use .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you, the idea of "secret" argument seems fine, but it is not the proper way of doing this. In which concerns the htaccess file, I will have to check more in details about, if you have any suggestion on how to do it, it will be perfect.

Comment: The idea with "htaccess" was about forbidding access to specifed route from this file level (you should be able easily find appropriate info about that). And this solution seems to be nor perfect as well but I didn't find any better. But maybe if you just want hide this against users and you don't care if anyone came to this route directly by chance, maybe will be enough if you make this route "unguessable" like "yourproject/mysearch12381923172384" ?

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict your route to a certain method by `_method` option in your `routing` configuration:

```
your_rote:
    pattern: /myProject/search
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:YourAction }
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

Comment: Thank you, but my route can be used for GET and POST. I know how to restrict for that, but I ould like to restrict the route to only be accessible from the twig template where my controller is embedded.

Comment: @Milos , what diff it makes if user types the search url. they will only see the search page. whats the problem in that

Comment: @thecatontheflat, in fact, when the user will type the search url, he will get only the search bar, not the search page, that's the problem. The search bar has his rout: MyProject/search and the search page: MyProject/search/{q}/{type}/...